# Laravel 5.4 incompatiblity - share() or set-> error?

Tags: php, laravel

After trying to debug for a long time I run into an error of where I a variable does not seem to retrieve a value from the database.

Here is the code I use:

```
use App\Setting;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use View;
use DB;
class SettingsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        if(\DB::connection()->getDatabaseName() && Schema::hasTable('settings') && \DB::table('settings')->count()){

            $setting = new Setting;

            config()->set('website_desc', $setting->gets('general')->website_desc);
            config()->set('website_keywords', $setting->gets('general')->website_keywords);
        }
    }

    public function register()
    {
        // this approach worked before updating to 5.4
        view()->share('website_desc',config('website_desc'));

        view()->share('website_keywords',config('website_keywords'));

        //does not work either 
        // View::share(['website_desc' => 'values', 'website_keywords' => 'values']);
    }
}
```

my App/setting.php looks like this

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Setting extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','attributes'];

    public function gets($name){

        $attributes = $this->where('name',$name)->value('attributes');

        if($attributes){
            return json_decode($attributes);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see anything that became incompatible?

This is the a database entry of the table settings and the column "attributes":

`{"website_name":"name","website_title":"title","website_desc":"description","website_keywords":"keywords","website_footer_text":"footer"}`

I am kind of at my wits end.

Comment: Are you trying to pass `$website_desc` and `$website_keywords` to you view file so you could access them there. Question is not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just edited the question, because I realized that the issue was that the variables don't seem to have a value.